# jQuery addClass to h1

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

I'm trying to added a class to an h1 element based on the text that is inside the h1 element.

```
var title = $("h1").text();
if (title == "Welcome") {
$("h1").addClass("hide");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4LjnT/

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery or Zepto.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4LjnT/3/ as @jantimon said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('h1').addClass(function(){
    return $(this).text() == 'Welcome' ? 'hide' : '';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4LjnT/4/).

Or, to reduce the needless calls to jQuery:

```
$('h1').addClass(function(){
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText) == 'Welcome' ? 'hide' : '';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4LjnT/6/).

And I *may* have had a few minutes to kill, which resulted in this plain JavaScript alternative:

```
Object.prototype.textToClass = function(needle,classToAdd){
    var len = this.length,
        classes = [],
        txt;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        txt = this[i].textContent || this[i].innerText;
        if (txt == needle){
            classes = this[i].className.split(/\s/);
            classes.push(classToAdd);
            this[i].className = classes.join(' ');
        }
    }
    return this;
};

document.getElementsByTagName('h1').textToClass('Welcome','hide');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4LjnT/7/).

References:

- jQuery

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).
  - [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
  - [Conditional Operator/ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className).
  - [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).
  - [`String.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I do have a couple of question. What is the purpose of the "?" and the empty ''?

Comment: You're very welcome! As for the `?` and such, see the references, look at the conditional/ternary operator in the references.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not loaded in this fiddle.

Also you are not wrapping your code in a `document.ready()` function, so there's a risk it might not be executed in the manner you want. Make sure to select jQuery from the "Frameworks & Extensions" dropdown  on the right. Also, always remember to check your browser's console to see if there are errors, it's a good sanity check for things like this. Happens to me all the time : )

**JS**

```
$(function(){

  var title = $("h1").text();

  if (title === "Welcome") {
    $("h1").addClass("hide");
  }

}); // end ready
```

Comment: Ok, added jQuery to the fiddle and it now works. I do have the document.ready statement in the code on my local machine, there must be something wrong with my jquery locally.

Comment: Is your console printing out any errors locally? Have you tried removing all other JS and just using your hide snippet?